# net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to output data from mysql database by button using ajax. And when you click on the button in the console, such an error comes out.
GET http://web4/404 net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Here is the code on the page

```
   $("#display").click(function() {                

     $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to display.php
       type: "GET",
       url: "display.php",             
       dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
       success: function(response){                    
           $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
           //alert(response);
       }

   });
});
});
```

Here's what I'm trying to deduce

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=web4;host=localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
    $dsn, $username, $password,
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM account ';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $one) {

    echo '<tr><td>';
    print $one['login'];
    echo '</td><td>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Use the Dev Tools on the browser and look at the **Network** tab.  You should see the redirects there.

Comment: To be getting too many redirects on (eventually) `GET http://web4/404` - _that url_ is redirecting. I.e. your url-not-found handling is not working as you intend. It's not the _first_ problem here (whatever is causing your app to redirect `/display.php` to `/404` is the problem you're asking about) but it's a significant factor to create confusion - as it did in this case.